# Creating Android UI like HTC Sense

Tags: android, htcsense

Do you have any idea what's the starting point to develop an UI for Android OS, similar with HTC SenseUI ?

Can I create that on top of Android or I need to get the Android source code ?

Thank you.

Florin Matincă

Comment: Don't make it like HTC sense, MOTOBLUR is always better. It won't glitch up at all, especially if you run it on your pc first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to modify the Android OS to some extent, but since Android is open source, that's not a problem.

The problem is getting it installed on phones - if you've noticed, the only companies that have custom UIs are also phone manufacturers, so they can just ship their phones with it installed. Also, if a new version of Android comes out, you'd need to get the new source, and modify most of it again.

Distribution would be a serious problem...

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

You're right, the distribution may be a problem. Maybe in the future versions for Android it will be easier to create custom UIs.

Answer (score 2):

HTC Sense consist of a variety of functions.
Some like the Lock Screen can be implemented as normal programs. The start screen for programs can as well.
The systems setting for example can't be easily replaced without going into the android source code.

Comment: Further more, sense extends beyond the start screen into the contacts, the music player, it's pretty much throughout the android system on any HTC device ...

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with xil3, there are some realy popular home screen replacements out there not restricted to a certain brand.

- [ADW.Launcher](http://jbthemes.com/anderweb/)
- [LauncherPro](http://www.launcherpro.com/)
- [HelixLauncher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=645683)
- [HelixLauncher2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=641216)

All four are available on market place and therefor the distribution is simple.

HelixLauncher (and 2) are based on the Launcher from android itself, for which the sources are available as a [git repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git). This means you could use these sources to start your own Home Screen replacement.

So have fun!